# Matching of a page title in a jquery selector in addition to other selectors

Tags: jquery

I have this default jQuery selector (a div element) for matching a specific element:

```
$('.myselectorid')
```

However this "myselectorid" appears in different pages of the site. I am thinking if it is possible to add a page title selector to the above original selector so that I could execute my jQuery implementation on a specific page only (specified by the page title).

Also I need all of them combined as one jQuery selector.

I also know that to retrieve the page title, it would be like this:

```
$('html head title').text();
```

However I am not sure how to combined the above selector to my original selector as one new selector. For example, supposing I would like it to match the selector on a page with title "This is my page title", can I do it like this?

```
$('.myselectorid[html head title="This is my page title"]')
```

If not, how would I do it so that all of them appears as one combined selector (without using .add etc.) and it matches the page title as well?

I'm not an expert of jQuery selectors, I would appreciate if someone can share some insights on this approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a class to the body tag and then check if I should run that code based on what page I am on.

```
if ($("body.className").length > 0) {
    // Place the logic pertaining to the page with the class
    //$('.myselectorid') code here
}
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410298/one-js-file-for-multiple-pages) for more ideas along this line.