# set default value to more than 1 product ID using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have set default value to an input box and set it to readonly.
I also disable some select options.
It is working but when I add another ID for another product, only 1 ID works.

Please note that I don't have access to the actual html pages. I can only access the js file.

What I need is:
if I go to product 1 OR product 2, I will see the text box is set to 28 in readonly and the Weeks/Months disabled.

Below is my sample HTMLs.
***The HTMLs below are two different HTML pages.***

**HTML for product 1**

```
<p>Deliver products every <input type="text" id="thisInput_prod1"></p>
<select id="thisSelect_prod1">
    <option value="Days" selected>Days</option>
    <option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
    <option value="Month">Month</option>    
</select>
```

**HTML for product 2**

```
<p>Deliver products every <input type="text" id="thisInput_prod2"></p>
<select id="thisSelect_prod2">
    <option value="Days" selected>Days</option>
    <option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
    <option value="Month">Month</option>    
</select>
```

**This is the .js file**

```
window.onload = SetDefaultValue;

function SetDefaultValue() {

document.getElementById('thisInput_prod1').setAttribute('value','28');
document.getElementById('thisInput_prod1').readOnly = true;
var x = document.getElementById('thisSelect_prod1');
x.options[1].disabled=true;
x.options[2].disabled=true;

//below is to set the other product - I disable because its not working
//document.getElementById('thisInput_prod2').setAttribute('value','28');
//document.getElementById('thisInput_prod2').readOnly = true;
//var y = document.getElementById('thisSelect_prod2');
//y.options[1].disabled=true;
//y.options[2].disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: As you told me you are not a programmer, take a look at this post about [one JS file for multiple pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410298/one-js-file-for-multiple-pages) and to the blog of [P. Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/) who had this idea

Answer (score 0):

When there's no `thisInput_prod2` element, `document.getElementById('thisInput_prod2')` will evaluate to `null`, and then the code will abort trying to call `.setAttribute` on that null. You should assign it to a variable and test it to see if it's `=== null` before dereferencing it.

Comment: thanks for your comment but I don't know how to do that (not a programmer). product 1 and product 2 are two different HTML files, I actually have around 10 or more pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working example : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcq7ata/1/)

```
    document.getElementById('thisInput_prod1').value = '28';
    document.getElementById('thisInput_prod1').readOnly = true;
    var x = document.getElementById('thisSelect_prod1');
    x.options[1].disabled = true;
    x.options[2].disabled = true;

    document.getElementById('thisInput_prod2').readOnly = true;
    var y = document.getElementById('thisSelect_prod2');
    y.options[1].disabled=true;
    y.options[2].disabled=true;
```

Comment: sorry for the confusions, but product 1 and product 2 are two different html pages.

Comment: then I recommend you to check this answer about [JS for multiple pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410298/one-js-file-for-multiple-pages)

Comment: I am so sorry but I cannot understand that. I am not so programmer and just combining js codes from tutorials.